# Unity, script for rotating the camera by swiping (3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float sensitivityHor = 9.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float maximumVert = 45.0f;
    private float _rotationX = 0;
    private Rigidbody PlayerRigidbody;
 
    void Start()
    {
        PlayerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (PlayerRigidbody != null)
        {
            PlayerRigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
        float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor;
        float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    }
}
```

Good evening. I have written a script to rotate the camera by swiping a finger across the screen
(it is on my camera), everything works correctly with one finger, but if you touch with two fingers at the same time, the application will react incorrectly (suddenly change the camera rotation). How can I  fix it using Input.GetAxis or what can I use to write a script for multiple touches?

Comment: Make an allowance for a second touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use only the first touch for your movement, so that if there is a second nothing happens and change `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` by `Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y` with x and y respectively. Like this:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
    _rotationX -= Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y * sensitivityVert;
    _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
    float delta = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x * sensitivityHor;
    float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
}
```

Code not debugged, as its just your code with the substitution.
If handling the first touch acts weird, you can handle the rotation with the middle point maybe. Like this:

```
//get the touch middle when the second finger touches
if (Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
    touchMiddle = (Input.GetTouch(0).position + 
    Input.GetTouch(1).position) / 2;
    touchDistSqr = (Input.GetTouch(0).position - 
    Input.GetTouch(1).position).sqrMagnitude;
    return;
}
if (Input.touchCount == 2) {
    var deltaMidde = touchMiddle - (Input.GetTouch(0).position + Input.GetTouch(1).position) / 2;
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(deltaMidde.x, deltaMidde.y, 0);
}
```

All the code in the `LateUpdate()`.
Preferably camera movements needs to be done in the `LateUpdate()` for the objects that might have moved inside Update to be at their final state for each frame. As per adviced in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html).
Not really relevant but note that you can use `Vector2` instead of `Vector3`for the screen operations most of the time.

Also it is very interesting in the `Update` or `LateUpdate` operations to have them multiplied by `Time.deltaTime` so that the movement is frame rate independent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea, I've written  Input.touchCount - 1  instead of 0 because I have the buttons UI which move the player.